# How to solve Ooozie JA017 : Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID exception?

Tags: oozie

I am using **HDP 2.4** with oozie **version 2.4.**
After submitting oozie job,I am getting exception **"JA017:Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID"** in oozie log and get status as failed.
But my output directory created successfully i.e my workflow is running fine.
So why i got this exception ? how to resolve this ?Please suggest for any configuration setup or permission setup in details to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Oozie delegates the actual execution to YARN, then checks the job status in YARN from time to time. But your error message suggests that Oozie cannot get the status => job is supposed to be dead. So you have to **dig into the YARN logs** to understand what happened -- look at in the Oozie logs, extract the "external ID" for the last executed Action, then replace `job_11111_99999999` (legacy MR1 naming) with `application_11111_99999999` and use either YARN GUI or YARN command-line to retrieve the logs for that job.

Comment: did you check if output dir have refreshed data or not?

Comment: yes i have checked output dir have refreshed data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found duplicate Job ID.
Execution succeeds when I empty the directory */user/history/done_intermediate*.